# Filling Datagrid from remote http service

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying my first flex application. And have a problems adding data from xml http service to datagid.

My xml file looks like this:

```
<players>

  <player>
    <name>test</name>
    <status>F</status>
    <claimed>1</claimed>
  </player>

  <player>
    <name>meta</name>
    <status>F</status>
    <claimed>1</claimed>
  </player>
</players>
```

First I tried to fill the data in a raw way, so created mxml tag for HTTP service, and added handlers.

But very soon I realized that main application file became unreadable (because of huge amount of code), so I decided to organize it some way.

So decided to replace services with a separate as classes.

My new code looks like this:

MXML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
            layout="absolute" creationComplete="main()"  height="756" borderColor="#FFFFFF" width="950" top="10" left="10" horizontalAlign="left" verticalAlign="top" backgroundGradientAlphas="[1.0, 1.0]" backgroundGradientColors="[#FCFCFC, #FCFCFC]">

        <mx:Panel width="900" height="727" layout="absolute" title="Игра ГО" horizontalAlign="center" horizontalCenter="0" top="10">
        <mx:Script>
            <![CDATA[

                import goclient.ListOfPlayers;
                import goclient.usersList;
                import goclient.Tester;
                import mx.controls.Alert;
                // And makes periodical requests to the server
                [Bindable]
                public var users:ListOfPlayers;
                [Bindable]
                public var test:Tester; 

                public function main():void{
                    test = new Tester();
                    users = new ListOfPlayers();



                }           

            ]]>
        </mx:Script>


            <mx:DataGrid doubleClickEnabled="true" dataProvider="{users.getPlayersList()}" 
                x="10" y="157" width="860" height="520" id="userList">
                <mx:columns>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="claimed" headerText="Was claimed" width="25"/>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name of the player"  />
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="status" headerText="Status (Free or Busy)" />
                </mx:columns>
            </mx:DataGrid>
```

And the service class:

```
ListOfPlayers.as

package goclient
{
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.http.mxml.HTTPService;

    public class ListOfPlayers
    {
        public var usersListService:HTTPService;
        private var minTimer:Timer = new Timer(100000, 0);  
        private var playersData:ArrayCollection;    
        private var person:currentPerson; 

        public function ListOfPlayers()
        {
            usersListService = new HTTPService();
            usersListService.url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/go/active/";
            usersListService.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);
            //Alert.show("Here");
            sendData(); 
            //minTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, sendData);
            //minTimer.start();

        }

        public function getResp():String
        {
            return "Resr";
        }

        public function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            //person = new currentPerson(event.result.current.username, event.result.current.img, event.result.current.rank);
            playersData = event.result.players.player;
            Alert.show("resh");

        }
        public function sendData():void
        {
            usersListService.send();
        }

        public function getPlayersList():ArrayCollection
        {
            Alert.show(playersData.toString());
            return playersData;
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that nothing is shown in the datagrid

I am just a beginner, so please advice what did I wrong with the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result function (in ListOfPlayers class) should give the list of players and not the function that is calling the webservice.

What you could do is add this in server class:

```
[Bindable]
public var playersData:ArrayCollection;
```

and in your view add also this variable with the bindable tag and set the value add this line in main():
playersData = users.playersData;

then the datagrid dataprovider is "{playersData}"

this should work. But with XML list it is always a bit difficult to know how deep you are in the tree ;)

Comment: Could you please explain me a bit. When I was learning some books about OOD, everywhere I see, you should add private variables and public access functions (getters and setters)

And what I have to do now - define public variable in the class. Is that OK?

Comment: Indeed that is better practice. But you have to know when the playersData data is changed. I do this by making it Bindable. You can make a getter bindable but that is making the example a lot complexer. But it is better to do it with getters and setters.

Comment: One more thing:

I just noticed that there is a problem in this line:
playersData = event.result.players.player;

Seems it's more correct to create ArrayCollection here?
e.g. playersData = ArrayCollection(event.result.players.player);

But this code is not working (gives error that it can't convert array collection to array....) why?

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I guess this error is because you get a XML list back and you are just putting it in an arraycollection. Flex isn't able to do that. You could just use a XML or xmllist variable for playersData.